# Android HighChart Treemap - Treemap displays leaf nodes instead of parent nodes

Tags: android, charts, highcharts

I created a treemap with 3 levels. First level has only one element, 2nd level have 4 elements, and each element in 2nd level have 4 childs.  I want the treemap to show the 2nd level but right now it shows all the elements in 3rd level and when I click to one of them, it shows all the children of it's parents level.

To add parent I use

```
    HashMap<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("parent" , "parentId");
```

The traversal related code I tried

```
series.setLazoutAlgorithm("squarified");
series.setAllowTraversingTree(true);
series.setLevelIsConstant(false);
HILevels level = new HILevels();
levels.setLevel(1);
levels.setBorderWidth(3);
series.setLevels(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(level))));
```

Comment: Hi! I've noticed you created the thread with the same question at our Highcharts Forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50779&p=185902#p185902 . Since we work as a single team on different support channels, the thread will be continued there. Regards!